# Give the formula for a function with natural domain $(\infty ,0]\cup [10,\infty)$ and with range $(-\infty, -1]$

Tags: functions, generating-functions

As the title says, I need to create/generate a formula for a function with natural domain $(-\infty ,0] \cup [10, \infty )$ and with range $(-\infty , -1]$
where $-\infty $ means going off towards negative numbers' infinite, and $\infty$ means reaching towards positive infinite. $\cup$ means union, so all numbers from both sets $(-\infty ,0] \cup [10, \infty)$ combined. it means elements from $(-\infty ,0]$ "or" $[10, \infty)$

Also known as all numbers except for $(0,10)$ or $[1,9]$

how do you generate this type of function with a center section of the domain missing? I am able to create a function where there is only one type of restriction, but not a function where there's a set of numbers restricted.

Comment: Do you know about piece wise functions?

Comment: Note that $(0,10)$ and [1,9] are very different intervals.

Comment: i've seen it once on a test, but never actually learned the concept of it and how to use them/solve for them/anything related to them. I just very quickly googled it though, but how would that help when I need a formula? not sure how to write the formula for a piece-wise function, but after reading about the piece-wise functions, i think that this problem is definitely something to do with piece-wise functions.

Comment: @gticecream8 a formula for a piece-wise function is the same as any other, but you define the pieces on whatever intervals you would like. So you could have $x^2$ on the interval $[0,5)$ and $4.5x$ on $[5,\infty)$.

Comment: @Jeremy, why are they different? don't soft parentheses mean excluding 0 and 10, meaning [1,9] which is the same as the hard parenthesis that include 1 and 9, [1,9]? err.. if it's wrong, then what is the union of those two intervals in the problem?

Comment: Excluding $(0,10)$ should exclude e.g. 9.9, but only excluding $[1,9]$ doesn't exclude 9.9.

Comment: @jeremy oh I understand now, but then what would be a valid piecewise formula for this problem? would both equations in the piecewise formula have to share the given range {-∞ , -1]? what would the formula be?

Comment: @coffeemath ahhhh thank you for clearing that up for me! so then the interval (0,10) is excluded in the union in the problem, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=-1-\sqrt{|x-5|-5}$ works for this.

Explanation: The term $|x-5|$ is centered at 5, the center of the interval $(0,10)$ which you wish to excluded from the domain, and $0 \le |x-5|<5$ on $(0,10)$. So next, we see that $|x-5|-5$ is negative on $(0,10)$ so that the squareroot will not be defined there.

So far, $\sqrt{|x-5|-5}$ is symmetric around the point $(5,0)$ and has range $[0,\infty).$ So if we change its sign, the range becomes $(-\infty,0]$, and since we desire a range of $(-\infty,-1]$ we finally subtract $1$ from the formula to shift it vertically down by $1$ unit.

The plot has two lower-half sideways parabolas, one with vertex at $(10,-1)$ going down and to the right, and the other with vertex at $(0,-1)$ going down and to the left.

Comment: i tested it out, and it works! could you just explain it a bit? is the -1 part for the range? the absolute value is to restrict the domain, is that right?

Comment: @gticecream8 Just added "Explanation", let me know if other details unclear.

Comment: it's perfect, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We will change the problem a bit, to natural domain $(-\infty,-5]\cup [5,\infty)$. If we solve that problem we can shift to get what we want. We are doing this because symmetry is nice.

And although I have nothing really against $5$, but $1$ is a nicer number. So we will deal with natural domain $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)$. You can do the suitable scaling.

So we want to run into trouble in $(-1,1)$. The following sounds good:
$$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}.$$

But the range is $[0,\infty)$. That part is easy to fix: switch sign, and subtract $1$.

Comment: @coffeemath: Thanks, I had left out the $-1$. Too busy rhapsodizing about symmetry.

Comment: so then, -1 - √(1- (1/x^2))   ? is that what you meant by switch the sign and subtract 1?

Comment: thank you for your help though! i am beginning to  understand the problem much better

Comment: I meant $-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}-1$. Then for the scaling replace $x$ by $x/5$. Then for the shift replace the (new) $x$ by $x-5$. So we end up with $-\sqrt{1-\frac{25}{(x-5)^2}}-1$. (I wanted to show the thinking that went into the ultimate formula.)

Comment: You are welcome.